# parent class default constructor to be enter by user then through inheritance - C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

int my child class, when I use inheritence and settings the default with `: UserAccout("user","pass");` Is it possible to get input from `cin` instead?

Here are my code examples.

I have my parent class

```
class UserAcct
{
private:
    string  userName;
    string  userPassword;

public:
    UserAcct(string newUserName, string newPassword);       
    ~UserAcct();                                        
};
```

this is UserAcct.cpp

```
UserAcct::UserAcct(string newUserName, string newPassword)
{
   userName = newUserName;
   userPassword = newUserName;
}
```

this is my child class so to say

```
class GameSettings : public UserAcct
private:
    ofstream  odataBase("gameSettings.txt", ios::app);
    ifstream  idataBase("gameSettings.txt", ios::app);
    int       settingSet;
public:
    GameSettings(int newSettings);
```

the child class .cpp

```
GameSettings::GameSettings (int newSettings) : UserAcct("user","pass")//this right here
{ 
    settingsSet = newSettings;
}
```

ps. The inheritence doesnt work for some reason and I'm not sure why. Under the child class .cpp before the `:` in "`: UserAcct("user","pass");`" I get an error saying

> Error: expected a '{'

Comment: Where is `UserAccout` defined ?

Comment: I added the userAcct.cpp it is defined within there

Comment: `~User();` <-This is wrong

Comment: `UserAccout` <- this is not defined on the sample code.

Comment: sorry :| I have it changed in my code I just missed the change in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

You can get the input from `cin` by making a function call.

```
GameSettings::GameSettings (int newSettings) : UserAccout(getUserName(), getPassword()) {}
```

Where `getUserName()` can be a `static` member function of `GameSettings` or a non-member global function.

```
static std::string getUserName()
{
   std::string name;
   cin >> name;
   return name;
}
```

`getPassword()` can be a similar function.

**Question 2:**

You are seeing a compiler error since you ended the following with a `;`.

```
GameSettings::GameSettings (int newSettings) : UserAccout("user","pass");
                                                                        ^^^
```

The `;` needs to be replaced by `{}` and anything else that goes inside the body of the function.

**PS** You are using `UserAcct` and `UserAccout`. That needs to be fixed. Perhaps you should spell it out to avoid confusion the future. Use `UserAccount`.

Comment: You solved my first question, thank you. I wasn't sure if that was legal. In the second question, I made an edit. It is correct within my actual code and still gives that same error

Comment: @Robolisk, see the **PS** in my answer.

Comment: I did within my count, renamed it all to UserAccount, triple check spelling and still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Robolisk, I suspect the errors are caused by `ofstream  odataBase("gameSettings.txt", ios::app);` and the similar line. You cannot initialize a member variable using that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation needs a body:

```
GameSettings::GameSettings (int newSettings) : UserAccout("user","pass") { }
```

Comment: sorry, within my actual code it does have a body, I just didnt add it to the question. It still does not work.

Comment: Then check your spelling: UserAcct -> UserAccount -> User

there are 3 different versions of that^^